# Define RSS feed encoding

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encoding, groovy, google-reader

I am trying to process RSS feed using Google Reader API, but the issue is that even if feed encoding is UTF-8 it is returned in an unreadable format.

```
resp.contentType = "text/xml"
resp.characterEncoding = "UTF-8"

URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/reader/public/atom/feed/" + rss);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
String line;
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    content.append(line + "\n");
}
reader.close();
def feed = new XmlParser().parseText(content.toString())
 ...
new XmlNodePrinter(resp.writer).print(feed)
```

Is  there are any additional encoding settings that I miss? The code runs on Google App Engine.

Comment: We're going to need more information than "it is returned in an unreadable format". What happens? How did you determine it was unreadable? Do you get an exception, and what's the stacktrace?

Comment: @Nick Non-English characters were rendered not properly, other were ok

Comment: I am using this example -> http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-rss-feed-example/, i have the same problem in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you do with more idiomatic Groovy?  I think all of your code can be replaced by:

```
def feed = new URL( "http://www.google.com/reader/public/atom/feed/$rss" ).withReader( 'UTF-8' ) { r ->
  new XmlParser().parse( r )
}

...

new XmlNodePrinter( resp.writer ).print( feed )
```

Comment: Excellent, I do not know why but now it's ok. What could be the reason?

Comment: Not sure...  There might have been something up with the stream->reader charset chain.  Looks ok though, just a little long winded ;-)

Comment: How to use it in spring mvc? with --> this example --> http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-rss-feed-example/